# Firebird y codeignter

Tags: php, codeigniter, firebird

alguien sabe con exactitud que significa este error en firebird

> This column cannot be updated because it is derived from an SQL
>   function or expression.Attempted update of read-only column.

En codeigniter:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: ibase_query(): attempted update of read-only column
>
> Filename: firebird/firebird_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 607

En la linea 607 es una función insert_blob(), donde la misma convierte string a blob.
No voy a colocar la consulta por que no puedo cambiarla, asi que no viene al caso que escriba el sql, pero si alguien sabe con exactitud que es lo que significa se lo voy a agradecer.
Me sucede cuando intento insertar datos a cierta tabla.

Saludos y espero que me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0):

La documentación oficial dice lo siguiente:

> Este mensaje de error puede aparecer cuando intenta actualizar una
>   columna calculada. Puesto que tal columna se calcula, no se puede
>   escribir los valores directamente en ella. Si realmente necesita un
>   valor específico, es necesario cambiar la fuente computarizada.

Lo que significa que en la base de datos esa columna puede estar siendo utilizada por algun trigger, asi que si quieres poder actualizar esa columna deberías desactivar ese trigger y despues actualizar la columna.

En el siguiente enlace puedes leer más información:

http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq331/